# Regex to match string not ending in pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I want to match strings not ending in `/\(.*\) */`. I tried `^[^\(].*[^\)] *$` (and also a bunch of things with `(?!something)`, but I had no luck there), but it matches "`()`" and so.

A few more examples: http://rubular.com/r/zdxxW6IWUf

Comment: Which language are you matching in?

Comment: sed -E, but using rubular to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
/^[^(]*[^)] *$/
```

[The demo.](http://rubular.com/r/qVwbNrCMEq)

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want any type of words that doesn't finish with parenthesis like a function?

Like in:

func() **gerg**  **erg**   **aerg**   aergaerga() **gaergjaij** f() **g**  **arg** gre()

If yes, try `\<\w+(?!\(\))\>`

edit:
[Rubular](http://rubular.com) doesn't seem to support word boundaries, so you can try `\b\w+(?!\(\))\b`. Click to see the example [Here](http://rubular.com/r/BfFHkDBx65).

Otherwise, could you please explain in more details what you mean?

Comment: yes, that is what I want, but that regex doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

would this suffice?

```
/[^)]$/
```

Or, if it's necessary to ignore trailing whitespace too:

```
/[^}]\w*$/
```

If your RE tool doesn't support `\w`, just change it to `[ \t]`